# pass variable from Model to View by Apllication Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 4.

In controller/application_controller.rb.
I want to pass from Cuisine Model to View to make sidebar using **helper_method**:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :sidebar_values

  def sidebar_values
    @food_types = FoodType.all
    @cuisines = Cuisine.all
  end
end
```

and in view/layout/application.html.erb

```
<div class="panel">
       Cuisine List:

      <% @cuisines.each do |c| %>
           <%= c.name %>
       <% end %>
 </div>
```

But i received an error:

**undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass**
at this line:

***<% @cuisines.each do |c| %>***

What wrong i'm do here??? Ensure Cuisine Model have some value.

Comment: You haven't actually called the `sidebar_values` method, and so `@cuisines` hasn't been defined.  In Ruby, undefined instance variables (ones starting with @) evaluate to nil.

Comment: so how can i call @cuisines or pass this variable by that way ???

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `sidebar_values`in your controller or view.  Then `@cuisines` will be defined and you can use it.

Since you want it in the default layout, to be used in all pages (i assume), i would call it in a before_filter in ApplicationController, like so

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :sidebar_values

  def sidebar_values
    @food_types = FoodType.all
    @cuisines = Cuisine.all
  end
end
```

Your view code from your question should now work.

Notes:

- "set_sidebar_values" is actually a nicer name for that method.
- i changed it so it's not a helper method any more - there's no point having it as a helper if it's going to always be called by the controller anyway.  But you could add it back in if you decide to not call it in a before_filter

Comment: thanks for your effort, but i receive error "undefined local variable or method `sidebar_values'" . i am call sidebar_values at application layout.

The question start from reading this book "Rails 4 Apllication Development" - Saurabh Bhatia - at Project 1: Create a recipe-sharing website

Comment: You need to **either** make it a helper and call it in the view **or** call it in the controller.  It sounds like you are not making it a helper, but calling it in the view.   Replace "before_filter" with "helper_method" in my solution.  Or, don't call it in the view if you have used the before_filter, as it will have been called already and the variables will be defined already.

Comment: BTW there's no point saying "i am doing such and such a book" as that assumes that we all have that book to hand and are willing to look up the tutorial in question.  This is usually not the case.  Always assume no prior knowledge of your problem when asking a question, ie explain what needs to be explained.

Answer (score 0):

In `application_controller.rb`,You can set instance variables which will be available on every request throughout

```
before_filter :get_cuisines_for_navbar
def get_cuisines_for_navbar

     @cuisines=   Cuisine.all.map(&:name).uniq

end
```

So `@cuisines` is available in the layout/view/navigation...whereever you want and easily accessible

```
<div class="panel">
       Cuisine List:

      <% @cuisines.each do |c| %>
           <%= c.name %>
       <% end %>
 </div>
```